# clone html form with oninput event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script like the following:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, 
        newNum  = new Number(num + 1), 
        newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); 
    newElem.find('.input_1').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_a').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_a').val('1');
    newElem.find('.input_2').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_b').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_b').val('1');
    newElem.find('.output_1').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_o').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_o').val('');
    $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
});
});
</script>

<form action="#" id="form" oninput="o.value = parseInt(a.value) * parseInt(b.value)">
<div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
    <input class="input_1" name="a" type="text" value="1"> *
    <input class="input_2" name="b" type="text" value="1"> =
    <output class="output_1" name="o"></output>
</div>
</form>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add row">
```

If those code is executed, the result of multiplication of numbers in the first row will be given automatically and correctly. But if the addition of the line (ie the second row and so on), the multiplication between the two entry not run automatically. Is there a mistake on my script that?

Comment: Possible to provide fiddle or plunker for your issue.

Comment: this my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/puspo/q9o1po9k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your input event handler. You can use a function called `updateChange` which read and update the values of your new nodes.

I've change the `id` of you first `entry1` because you use this name in your new entries. This not affect your problem.

```
<form action="#" id="form">
    <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
        <input class="input_1" id="ID1_a" type="text" value="1"> *
        <input class="input_2" id="ID1_b" type="text" value="1"> =
        <output class="output_1" id="ID1_o"></output>
    </div>
</form>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add row">
```

JS

I've created a function `updatechange` which read your inputs when an `input event` is trigger and update the `output`.

```
$(function() {
   function updateChange() {
     var childNodes = this.children;
     var childNodesLen = this.children.length;
     var i=0;
     var inputs,outputs;
     for (;i<childNodesLen;i++){
       inputs = childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
       outputs = childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName('output');
       outputs[0].value = parseInt(inputs[0].value) * parseInt(inputs[1].value);
     }
  };
  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('input',updateChange);    

$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  var num = $('.clonedInput').length,
   newNum = new Number(num + 1),
   newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');
   newElem.find('.input_1').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_a').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_a').val('1');
   newElem.find('.input_2').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_b').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_b').val('1');
   newElem.find('.output_1').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_o').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_o').val('');
   $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
   $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
  });
 });
```

I recommend you that you use plain JavaScript to manipulate your DOM. It is equal easy that using jQuery ;-)